# Google Analytics iOS: how does it track users?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in an iOS app, without IDFA enabled and without the User ID feature.

The analytics reports refer to new vs returning users, and of course shows other data based on the user's behavior in the app.

My question: How does GA track a user that terminates the app and restarts it? I understand it can't be using UDID to connect the two app sessions, per Apple limitations.

I am trying to understand whether a user that terminates the app and restarts it, or uninstalls the app and re-installs it, will appear in GA as one user or multiple.

Note: I don't need to know anything about the user identity, just their usage of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics creates unique cid (client id) the first time the app runs. Active/returning users report is based on the number of distinct cid value Google Analytics receives from the app. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app for example will generate new client id and it will appear in the report as new user. IDFA is not required for active users report although if provided it allows for demographic reports.

Comment: OK, so the important thing is that a delete & reinstall will create a new user. If I'm testing the live app, this can happen a few times.

Answer (score 1):

Usually those kind of framework create their own udid, and save it into the keychain. Data saved in the keychain persist even after app uninstall, but not after a device restore.